# Screencast of native Trigger.io features?

Tags: trigger.io

I need to build a mobile application for a client. I've been looking at solutions like Trigger.io to simplify the task for me. I've read through the documentation but I haven't found any examples of what the native functionality *looks* like?

My main concern is that a solution like Trigger.io will have its own branding on the chrome/UI rather than using the phone's native chrome/UI. I need to deliver a product to my client that has zero third-party branding & style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just posted a [screencast demo on our blog](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/04/23/screencast-showing-trigger-io-forge-in-action/) which also talks about but does not explicitly show native features.

It gives an introduction to the framework and I'll follow it up with another screencast focused on native features next week. You have control of the styling with the native UI components, as documented here for the top bar for example where you can set the button images and background tint:
http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/topbar.html